# Android vector asset fatal exception after pull from version control

Tags: android, exception, button, vector

We use Bitbucket and after the last commit, vector images don't work.

```
12-03 12:48:58.214 26158-26158/linegraphapp.linegraphapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: linegraphapp.linegraphapp, PID: 26158
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060064
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1378)
```

If I create the same button in my local copy, all works fine.
what could be wrong?

My layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".AddPicture">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/plus_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/plus_btn"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Add"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>

</menu>
```

Button code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="34dp"
    android:height="34dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FFF"
    android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z"/>
```

If it needs, I will add full stack trace.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKJgX.png)

I use compileSdkVersion 26 and Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: in which api version you got error ?

Comment: I use compileSdkVersion 26